# Deallocate a linked list in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

So I created a linked list and printed out it's results but when I try deallocating the list it doesn't work.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
node = root;
node = [node next];

while([node next] != nil)
{
  ListNode *temp;
  temp = [node next];
  free(node);
  node = temp;
}
```

Problem is when I run it I just get an error message that says: `Error in ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0909720c`

I don't understand what the error message means and I don't know how to fix it.

This is the interface:

```
@interface ListNode : NSObject
{
@private
    int value;
    ListNode* next;
}

- (id) setValue: (int) value_value;
- (int) value;
- (id) setNext: (ListNode*) next_value;
- (ListNode*) next;

@end
```

Comment: There is not enough code to figure out the problem, but in general, you shouldn't be calling `free` on an Objective-C object.

Comment: Then how do you delete an object in Objective C? I can show you more code if you need it.

Comment: You should probably show your `@interface` code, how you create `ListNode` objects, and tell us if automatic reference counting (ARC) is enabled in your project (if you're using a recent-enough Xcode, it is by default).

Comment: Do you also want to see how I implemented the free method?

Comment: I was assuming that you were using the `free` function from the C standard library. Is that not the case?

Comment: Either way, assuming that ARC is enabled, to free a list node, you need to unlink it from its parent by doing something like `[parent setNext: nil]`. Objective-C objects are deleted when there are no references left to them.

Comment: Yes that's correct, does that mean I don't have to include anything in the interface or implementation files? Also I added that command before using `free(node)` and I still the same error.

Comment: You must not call `free` at all on them.

Comment: So does free just not exist in objective c?

Comment: `free` is the counterpart to `malloc`. You must not call `free` on something that was not allocated with `malloc`. It exists in Objective-C, but only for compatibility with C allocations, not for objects.

Comment: I tried your fix and it work, but does that actually dellocate the linked list? I tried printing the linked list again and although it didn't print them out I didn't get a segfault which I assumed would happen if you're trying to access memory that doesn't exist.

Comment: Assuming your project has ARC enabled, yes, that's all you need. You may want to read about it.

Comment: So if I'm writing this in Linux without any type of IDE can I assume that my project is not ARC enabled? Is Automatic Reference Counting something that isn't naturally in objective C? This is my first time programming it so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Objective-C implementation on Linux that supports ARC. You will need to use the `retain`/`release` methods instead. The oversimplified story is that `release` will free your objects, but you definitely should look it up ("objc retain release" seems to have some good results on Google).

Comment: [The GNUstep runtime](https://github.com/gnustep/libobjc2) supports all modern Objective-C features, including ARC. You have to compile with clang, not gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each objects in Objective-C has a “retain count”, and when the retain count becomes zero, the system deallocates the object. You don't ever force an object to be deallocated by calling `free` on it. You just get rid of all your references to it.

You need to read [Cocoa Core Competencies: Object Ownership](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH67-SW1) immediately. This sentence in particular addresses your question:

> When there are no remaining strong references to an object, the object gets deallocated.

Comment: *When the retain count would become zero* is a more accurate statement.  It's rare for the retain count to ever actually be zero.